Socket.IO Client Error: "GET http://localhost:9094/socket.io/ 404 (Not Found)"
I am trying to implement a chat application using Socket.IO in my Node.js backend and React frontend. However, I am encountering an issue where the client is unable to connect to the Socket.IO server. I receive the following error in the browser console:
Chat.js:12 
GET http://localhost:9094/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P0JdnSJ 404 (Not Found)
create @ polling.js:298
Request @ polling.js:237
request @ polling.js:190
doPoll @ polling.js:215
poll @ polling.js:96
doOpen @ polling.js:56
open @ transport.js:46
open @ socket.js:170
Socket @ socket.js:111
open @ manager.js:108
connect @ socket.js:189
(anonymes) @ Chat.js:12
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23150
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:24926
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24891
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24878
commitPassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24866
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27039
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26935
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26117
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
(anonymes) @ react-dom.development.js:25651


Backend (Node.js with Express and Socket.IO) - index.js:
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const http = require('http');
const path = require("path");
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const { User, Conge, DocumentRequest, Notification, Feedback, Event, Message } = require("./Config");
const app = express();
const crypto = require('crypto');
const multer = require('multer');
const fs = require('fs');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const cors = require('cors');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const session = require('express-session');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const server = http.createServer(app);
require('./Passport');

app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000', credentials: true }));
app.use(flash());

app.use(helmet({
  contentSecurityPolicy: {
    useDefaults: true,
    directives: {
      "img-src": ["'self'", "data:", "http://localhost:9094"]
    },
  },
  crossOriginResourcePolicy: { policy: 'cross-origin' },
  crossOriginOpenerPolicy: { policy: 'same-origin' }
}));

app.use('/profilePictures', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads', 'profilePictures')));

// More app.use and routes here...

// Socket.IO setup
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    credentials: true
  }
});

// Socket.IO connection
const clients = {};

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(`User connected: ${socket.id}`);

  socket.on('register', (userId) => {
    clients[userId] = socket.id;
    io.emit('userStatusChange', { userId, status: 'online' });
    console.log(`User ${userId} registered with socket ID: ${socket.id}`);
  });

  socket.on('private message', async ({ recipientId, message, userId }) => {
    const timestamp = new Date().toISOString();
    console.log(`Received message from ${socket.id} for ${recipientId}: ${message}`);

    const newMessage = new Message({
      senderId: userId,
      recipientId: recipientId,
      message: message,
      timestamp: timestamp
    });

    try {
      await newMessage.save();
      console.log('Message saved to database');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error saving message to database:', error);
    }

    const recipientSocketId = clients[recipientId];
    if (recipientSocketId) {
      io.to(recipientSocketId).emit('private message', { message, senderId: userId, timestamp, recipient: recipientId });
      io.to(socket.id).emit('private message', { message, senderId: userId, timestamp, recipient: recipientId }); // Echo message to sender
      console.log(`Message sent from ${socket.id} to ${recipientSocketId}: ${message}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`User ${recipientId} is not connected`);
    }
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log(`User disconnected: ${socket.id}`);
    for (let userId in clients) {
      if (clients[userId] === socket.id) {
        delete clients[userId];
        io.emit('userStatusChange', { userId, status: 'offline' });
        break;
      }
    }
  });
});

// Routes
app.get('/api/current-user',async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id).select('-password');
    res.json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

app.get('/api/userss', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await User.find();
    res.json(users);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

app.get('/fetchMessages/:userId/:otherUserId', async (req, res) => {
  const { userId, otherUserId } = req.params;
  try {
    const messages = await Message.find({
      $or: [
        { senderId: userId, recipientId: otherUserId },
        { senderId: otherUserId, recipientId: userId }
      ]
    }).sort({ timestamp: 1 });
    res.json(messages);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send('Error fetching messages');
  }
});

// Routes and other configurations...

const port = process.env.PORT || 9094;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});

Frontend (React) - Chat.js:
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { socket } from '../socket';
import './Chat.css';

const Chat = ({ currentUser }) => {
  const [recipientId, setRecipientId] = useState(null);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const messagesEndRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Connecting to socket...');
    socket.connect();
    socket.emit('register', currentUser);

    socket.on('private message', ({ message, senderId, timestamp, recipient }) => {
      console.log('Received message:', { message, senderId, timestamp, recipient });
      setMessages(prevMessages => [...prevMessages, { text: message, sender: senderId, recipient, timestamp }]);
      scrollToBottom();
    });

    socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
      console.error('Connection failed:', error);
    });

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, [currentUser]);

  const sendMessage = () => {
    if (message.trim() && recipientId) {
      socket.emit('private message', { recipientId, message, userId: currentUser });
      setMessage('');
      scrollToBottom();
    }
  };

  const scrollToBottom = () => {
    if (messagesEndRef.current) {
      messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="chat-container">
      <div className="people-list">
        {/* UserList Component */}
      </div>
      <div className="chat">
        <div className="chat-header clearfix">
          {/* Chat header */}
        </div>
        <div className="chat-history">
          <ul className="m-b-0">
            {messages.map((msg, index) => (
              <li className="clearfix" key={index}>
                <div className={`message-data ${msg.sender === currentUser ? "text-right" : ""}`}>
                  <div className="message-data-time DT">{msg.timestamp}</div>
                  <img
                    src={`http://localhost:9094/images/${msg.sender === currentUser ? "sender.png" : "recipient.png"}`}
                    alt="Admin"
                    className={`rounded-circle ${msg.sender === currentUser ? "" : "float-right"}`}
                    width={100}
                    height={50}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className={`message ${msg.sender === currentUser ? "my-message" : "other-message float-right"}`}>
                  {msg.text}
                </div>
              </li>
            ))}
            <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="chat-message clearfix">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter text here..."
            value={message}
            onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
            onKeyPress={(e) => {
              if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                sendMessage();
              }
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;


Frontend (React) - socket.js:
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const SOCKET_URL = "http://localhost:9094"; // your backend URL

export const socket = io(SOCKET_URL, {
  autoConnect: false,
  withCredentials: true,
});


